# unable to connect sctp client from my host node to k8s pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am running a sctp server in a k8s pod as app. However, when I try to connect to that from my sctp client program running on my node where k8s is installed. I tried both using cluster ip or node port IP, but nothing is getting connected.

docker file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sctp-app
spec:
  replicas: 1            
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sctp-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sctp-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: sctp-container
          image: shardulkumar/sctpserversha:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 62324
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sctp-service
spec:
  #type: NodePort         
  selector:
    app: sctp-app
  ports:
    - name: sctp-port
      protocol: SCTP      
      port: 62324
      targetPort: 62324
      #nodePort: 30000
```

k8s cmds output

```
/home/ravi/mylearnings/sctp-k8s-proj>sudo kubectl get pods
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
sctp-app-77fc96c77-wtdjj   1/1     Running   0          61m
/home/ravi/mylearnings/sctp-k8s-proj>
/home/ravi/mylearnings/sctp-k8s-proj>
/home/ravi/mylearnings/sctp-k8s-proj>sudo kubectl get svc
NAME           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)      AGE
kubernetes     ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP      4d12h
sctp-service   ClusterIP   10.99.73.206   <none>        62324/SCTP   62m
/home/ravi/mylearnings/sctp-k8s-proj>
/home/ravi/mylearnings/sctp-k8s-proj>
/home/ravi/mylearnings/sctp-k8s-proj>telnet 10.99.73.206 62324
Trying 10.99.73.206...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
/home/ravi/mylearnings/sctp-k8s-proj>
```

I am running SCTP server as a container in k8s pod. Container listens at port 62324. I am facing same issue with nodeport configuration as well.

How can this connectivity issue be fixed?

Comment: when you say trying from the node you mean worker node ? or that's your Linux machine where k8s is installed with minikube and trying to access cluster IP? if that's the case clusterIP not get access that way, if you are truing from the worker node then it should be accessible.

Comment: node means where my k8s cluster is installed. it is a single node cluster and i am able to ping to cluster ip of any pod in k8s. but i am not able to connect to sctp server running. i tried with node port as well as cluster ip port

Comment: Refer to [Supported protocols](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/networking/service-protocols/#protocol-support).